# Prevent iTunes updates from recreating desktop shortcut

Tags: windows-7, itunes

Every time there's an iTunes update, the updater recreates a shortcut to iTunes on my desktop (that I don't want) which I must then delete.

I will reserve my ranting about [why this behavior is utterly unacceptable](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061101-03/?p=29153), but how do I stop iTunes from recreating a desktop shortcut every time it updates?

Comment: If command line parameters get passed to `msiexec` and there's an option still buried in the `.msi` files,  you might get lucky. It's a lot of "ifs" that have to line up though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to stop this. There used to be an option to "add a shortcut to the desktop," but Apple removed the option a long time ago in a version far far away.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine would be to remove writing permissions on the desktop. Possibly by creating another user with admin rights but without desktop permissions, and RunAs the installer with it. Unfortunately, the auto-updates are started on your regular user at launch, so you'd need to modify the registry startup to run it as that user, but these changes are likely to be reverted by the installation anyway.

Sigh, just delete the icon or complain to Apple (they won't listen).